Calculating Uniswap V3 pool address in Python
I'm trying to use Python to calculate the pool address of two tokens based on the Uniswap V3 Solidity code provided here.
Here's my Python code:
from web3 import Web3
from eth_abi.packed import encode_packed

factory = "0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984" # Uniswap V3 factory
init_code_hash = "0xe34f199b19b2b4f47f68442619d555527d244f78a3297ea89325f843f87b8b54" # POOL_INIT_CODE_HASH

token_a = "0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48" # USDC
token_b = "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2" # WETH
fee = 3000 # 0.3%

token_a, token_b = (token_a, token_b) if token_a.lower() < token_b.lower() else (token_b, token_a)

abi_encoded_1 = encode_packed(["address", "address", "uint24"], (token_a, token_b, fee))
salt_ = Web3.solidity_keccak(["bytes"], ["0x" + abi_encoded_1.hex()])
abi_encoded_2 = encode_packed(["address", "bytes32"], (factory, salt_))

pool_address = Web3.solidity_keccak(["bytes", "bytes"], ["0xff" + abi_encoded_2.hex(), init_code_hash])[12:]
pool_address = Web3.to_checksum_address(pool_address.hex())

print(pool_address)

However, when I try to run the code, I get 0x0f6733C487bb38A5779E0037aa3EaC384fcFbd33 as the pool address instead of 0x8ad599c3a0ff1de082011efddc58f1908eb6e6d8, as shown here.
I'm using Python 3.11.2, web3 6.11.3 and eth-abi 4.2.1.
Thank you in advance for your help.
